# Unity VideoPlayer: Missing Rewind-Method

Tags: unity-game-engine

The idea is to take an 360-degree Video and map it to the sky box using the "Unity Interactive 360 Video Sample" from the asset store scene. The Camera moved through a mall at recording time.

We want the video's spectator to be able to "walk forwards", to "walk backwards", "to stand still" in the mall in VR in Unity at running time.

To do so we want to use the oculus joystick to move the player through the video. That is, scrolling the current video clip time forwards and backwards at runtime using the value from `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")`.

Does work: Moving forwards works like a charm.
Does not work: Moving backwards does not work because playback speed cannot be negative.

This is the current script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class OculusInput_VideoControl : MonoBehaviour {

    VideoPlayer videoPlayer = null;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        videoPlayer = (VideoPlayer)FindObjectOfType(typeof(VideoPlayer));

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        float joystickPosition_from_minusone_to_one = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        videoPlayer.playbackSpeed = joystickPosition_from_minusone_to_one;

        OVRDebugConsole.print(videoPlayer.playbackSpeed + " ### " + joystickPosition_from_minusone_to_one );

    }
}
```

These are the systems specs:

[image: System specs]

How do we embed walking backwards?

```
if (joystickPosition_from_minusone_to_one < 0) videoPlayer.time -= (int) Mathf.Abs(joystickPosition_from_minusone_to_one);
```

is laggy!

```
if (joystickPosition_from_minusone_to_one < 0) videoPlayer.frame -= (int) Mathf.Abs(joystickPosition_from_minusone_to_one * 10);
```

is laggy too!

Answer (score 0):

[Negative playback speed is platform dependant.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-playbackSpeed.html)

If it is laggy, then this could be because of your platform.

You can and should however multiply the value you want to substract with Time.deltaTime.
It will probably improve your lag issue, but might not fix it completely.

Also, why Cast your Mathf.Abs to int? Is there a special reason for it?

Casting to int will round your float, which may be undesired behaviour.

Try the following code

```
if (joystickPosition_from_minusone_to_one < 0) 
{
    videoPlayer.time -= Mathf.Abs(joystickPosition_from_minusone_to_one) * Time.deltaTime;
}
```